# Comparing strings in JavaScript - logical mistakes?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple time parser that says when the things was published. If it's less that hour ago - it says "less that an hour ago" and so - you get the point.

For this, I used JavaScript! Here's my start:

```
var TimeMachines = {
  adjustTime: function(el) {
    var current = new Date(),
        day = current.getDate(),
        month = current.getMonth() + 1,
        year = current.getFullYear(),
        hour = current.getHours(),
        minutes = current.getMinutes();

    var sameDay,
        sameHour,
        sameMinute;

    var hourAgo,
        fourHoursAgo,
        sixHourAgo;

    if(day < 10) {
      day = '0'+day;
    }

    if(month < 10) {
      month = '0'+month;
    }

    if(hour < 10) {
      hour = '0'+hour;
    }

    if(minutes < 10) {
      minutes = '0'+minutes;
    }

    el.each(function() {
      var fullDate = $(this).text(),
          separatedDate = fullDate.split(' '),
          separatedDay = separatedDate[0],
          separatedHour = separatedDate[1],
          onlyHour = separatedHour.split(':');

      // check if day is the same
      if((day+'.'+month+'.'+year) === separatedDay) {
        sameDay = true;
      }

      if(hour == onlyHour[0]) {
        sameHour = true;
      }

      // if same hour
      if(sameHour && sameDay) {
        el.text('mniej niż godzinę temu')
      }

      if(sameHour && (parseInt(minutes) - parseInt(onlyHour[1]) <= 30)) {
        el.text('przed chwilą')
      }

      // if same day
      if(sameDay) {
        el.text('dzisiaj');
      }

    });
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  TimeMachines.adjustTime($('.datetime'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<time class="datetime">10.12.2014 13:00</time>
```

Problem is with comparing. It always says `dzisiaj`, so for what it seems, it stops after `if(sameDay){}`.

What can I do to properly target my exceptions?

Comment: Decorate your code with `else` accordingly. At the moment you'll always get `sameDay` result overriding all the above ones.

Comment: @raina77ow - I tried it, see here: http://codepen.io/kinetikc/pen/ZYQdRj? with no better results.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal `sameDay = true;` is there.

Comment: "it stops after `if(sameDay){}`" - Well, there *is* nothing after that `if` block.  What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @TomekBuszewski why reinvent the wheel? Can't you use timeago.js?

Comment: @David Read my code, I want it to trigger the _first_ `if` statement if find fitting.

Comment: @AmitJoki thanks for the plugin, but I want something written by myself ;-)

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: It will.  That's how `if` statements work.  It will trigger *any* and *every* `if` statement which results in a `true` value.  When you step through this in a debugger, where does the logic behave differently than you expect?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: Check my pen - http://codepen.io/kinetikc/pen/ZYQdRj - it returns `dzisiaj`, even if some conditions are met earlier.

Comment: Is the function() object [a valid parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) of jQuery .each() in the case of `el.each(function() {`?

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for a debugger.  Step through your code in a debugger and watch what's happening.  The code is doing *exactly* what it's written to do.  That last `if` block is going to write the value `dzisiaj` any time `sameDay` is `true`.  Given that today is `10.12.2014`, why is this surprising?

Comment: It turned out that adding `return` before the end of each statement solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the function you've got an if statement that will set the text to 'dzisiaj' if `sameDay` is true, this will always happen whether or not the other if conditions were true.

You could use else statements as raina77ow suggests:

```
// if same hour
if(sameHour && sameDay) {
    el.text('mniej niż godzinę temu')
}

else if(sameHour && (parseInt(minutes) - parseInt(onlyHour[1]) <= 30)) {
  el.text('przed chwilą')
}

// if same day
else if(sameDay) {
  el.text('dzisiaj');
}
```

Or you could use early return statements:

```
// if same hour
if(sameHour && sameDay) {
  el.text('mniej niż godzinę temu')
  return;
}

if(sameHour && (parseInt(minutes) - parseInt(onlyHour[1]) <= 30)) {
  el.text('przed chwilą')
  return;
}

// if same day
if(sameDay) {
  el.text('dzisiaj');
  return;
}
```